# Is there any reason to use extern for constants anymore?

Tags: c++, c++20

In my earlier days I often had constructs like:

```
// .h
extern const int MY_CONST;

// .cpp
const int MY_CONST = 5;
```

Is it true that this is completely superseded by:

```
// .h
inline const int MY_CONST = 5;
```

Is there any reason to use the first variant nowadays?

Note that the latter has higher readability because the value is visible in the header file (self-documenting).

Comment: Hmm, maybe even better to write `constexpr int MY_CONST = 5` nowadays - for what reason did they invent the inline scenario? : D

Comment: I would say even better not to use UPPERCASE for constants. That's antipattern which works completely opposite way it was created for.

Comment: `constexpr` at the global scope is not inline by default

Comment: @Slava what do you mean with `which works completely opposite way it was created for`? imho the only reason not to use uppercase is to avoid conflicts with macros which are usually written in uppercase.

Comment: @t.niese that habit comes from times when C++ constants defined the C way, using preprocessor macro. And preprocessor macro is all uppercase to avoid conflicts with non macro stuff. Now constants are not macros anymore but that old habit stays and works exactly opposite way - increasing probability on conflict, which is nasty when preprocessor involved. People just too lazy to remember the reason that brought this habit and stop it when it is not actual anymore.

Comment: I think inline global variable in header file is allowed since C++17. Look here https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/07/23/how-to-define-a-global-constant-in-cpp/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Certainly. For the same reasons as one might want to define anything in separate translation unit. Same reasoning applies to function definitions for example.

For example, a reason may be to remove the need to recompile everything depending on the variable in case you want to change the initialiser.

Another reason may be that initialisation is complex and involves call to a function that you wish to hide because you may not want the dependency to be public.

Comment: Also, initialization might depend on prior initialization of another global object, or initialization of some other object might depend on initialization of this object, and you have to ensure the correct order of initialization by putting both objects in the same source file. +1.

Comment: @PeteBecker They can still both be inline variables defined in same header though.